# RSocket Net for the 3rd message frame the pipereader.ReadAsync is truncated causing an error in the MessageFramePeek method

Tags: rsocket

I am using RSocket.Net for a net client to a Java Spring Boot RSocket server. The server sends back quote messages to the client. The example code is working until the 3rd quote message, which is being truncated.

In [RSocketProtocol.Handler.cs](https://github.com/rsocket/rsocket-net/blob/master/RSocket.Core/RSocketProtocol.Handler.cs#L24)

```
    static public async Task Handler(IRSocketProtocol sink, PipeReader pipereader, CancellationToken cancellation)
    {
        Logs.Enter();

        //The original implementation was a state-machine parser with resumability. It doesn't seem like the other implementations follow this pattern and the .NET folks are still figuring this out too - see the internal JSON parser discussion for how they're handling state machine persistence across async boundaries when servicing a Pipeline. So, this version of the handler only processes complete messages at some cost to memory buffer scalability.
        //Note that this means that the Pipeline must be configured to have enough buffering for a complete message before source-quenching. This also means that the downstream consumers don't really have to support resumption, so the interface no longer has the partial buffer methods in it.
        while (!cancellation.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            var read = await pipereader.ReadAsync(cancellation);
            var buffer = read.Buffer;
```

The 1st message is like this with buffer size 942

[image]

The next message is similar. Then the 3rd message is either a far too large size of 5657 !!?

[image]

Or it's far too small at 165

[image]

This causes an error in the `MessageFramePeek` method

```
static public (int Length, bool IsEndOfMessage) MessageFramePeek(ReadOnlySequence<byte> sequence) { var reader = new SequenceReader<byte>(sequence); return reader.TryRead(out byte b1) && reader.TryRead(out byte b2) && reader.TryRead(out byte b3) ? ((b1 << 8 * 2) | (b2 << 8 * 1) | (b3 << 8 * 0), true) : (0, false); }
```

*UPDATE* I checked the encoding type is JSON on the server and the client so that strings are not mixed with objects on the wire. There is still the same issue.

*UPDATE* The same issue happens if RSocket.Core is built on net-standard or net-framework.

Comment: can you please migrate that one to our issues? Thanks

Comment: @rupweb were you able to resolve this. I am doing something similar to what you implemented and facing similar issue

Comment: I can check later but i think not we came up with a workaround using signalR

Comment: I raised https://github.com/rsocket/rsocket-net/issues/24